# how to prevent other useQuery run in one component for React-Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

If there are multiple useQuery in one component, suppose one of the useQuery running and cause the component rerender, this also causes other useQuery run, how to solve this Problem?

```
function App() {

  const query1 = useQuery(['query1'], someFn);
  const query2 = useQuery(['query2'], anotherFn);
  const query3 = useQuery(['query3'], lastfn);

  return <>
      {query3.data.map(data => <span>{data.id}<span>)}
       <button onClick={() => query3.refetch}>click</button>
  </>

}
```

When click the button I just want to run query3, but query1 and query2 also run, how to prevent this to happen?

Comment: that button onClick function doesn't make much sense. The return value of useQuery is not a function that you can invoke, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. All 3 queries will run on mount of the component, in parallel ...

Comment: @TkDodo I have edited the question, when I click the button, i will call the refetch fucntion from query3, and the query3.data is updated and the compoent rerendered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const query1 = useQuery(['query1'], someFn, {enabled: false});
const query2 = useQuery(['query2'], anotherFn, {enabled: false});
const query3 = useQuery(['query3'], lastfn);

return <button onClick={() => query3()}>click</button>
```

If you you want to use query 1 for example you will need to use the refetch function. See this if you are not to sure: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries